# Проблема расширения списка статуса. В чем хранить статус?

Tags: java, ооп

Сразу приходят в голову следующие системы статусов:

С помощью массива и переменной:

```
String[] statuses;
String currentStatus;
```

С помощью листа и переменной:

```
List<String> statuses;
String currentStatus;
```

С помощью enum:

```
enum Status {
    FIRST_STATUS,SECOND_STATUS //... etc
}

Status status;
```

С помощью класса с статичными полями и приватным(и) конструктором(ами)(по-сути тот же enum):

```
class Status{
    public final static Static FIRST_STATUS;
    public final static Static SECOND_STATUS;
    //... etc

    static{
        FIRST_STATUS = new Status();
        SECOND_STATUS = new Status();
        //... etc
    }

    private Status(){}
}
```

С помощью интерфейса, показывать не буду - говорят, что хранение констант в интерфейсе - антипаттерн. Легко заменяется классом.

Допустим, нам нужно реализовать классы с следующими сигнатурами:

```
class MoveableObject{
    public boolean doesStay();
    public boolean doesMove();
}

class PersonObject{
    public boolean doesStay(); // тот же статус, что и у MoveableObject!
    public boolean doesMove(); // тот же статус, что и у MoveableObject!
    public boolean doesTalk();
}
```

Видим, что набор статусов `MoveableObject` входит в набор статусов `PersonObject`. Хочу отнаследовать `PersonObject` от `MoveableObject`, так как код `MoveableObject` полностью входит в код `PersonObject`. Из рассмотренных выше для этой задачи подходит только вариант с `List`.

Есть ли другие способы, я что-то упускаю?

Comment: List лучше массива, т.к. он переменной длинны. Enum лучше строки возможностью проверок на этапе компиляции. Попробуйте использовать list enum-ов. Единственный возможный минус-частые изменения возможных значений enum при апдейтах программы

Comment: @ЮрийСПб то есть нужно сформировать единый enum, где будет храниться вся возможная функциональность?

Comment: Правда, при таком подходе мы не можем быть уверены, что передан Enum правильного enum'а.

Comment: Сложно сказать однозначно. Может быть нужно несколько разных енамов. Всё о задачи зависит

Comment: @ЮрийСПб неужели нет наследования у enum? По-мне, так очевидная вещь. Она бы спасла, но в данный момент я могу запихнуть любой Enum вообще. Если бы было наследование, то я бы смог запихнуть только наследников, что дает хоть какую-то защиту. Что думаете, нужно использовать классы со статическими полями и приватным/protected конструктором?

Comment: @Miron Почитайте про статические поля и конструкторы... а еще почитайте что такое `enum` на самом деле и как он вообще появился и для чего. Может выясните почему нельзя наследоваться в енамах.

Comment: @Tsyklop Я знаю, что такое enum. Я думаю, можно было бы организовать, чтобы сигнатура у ребенка была та же, что и у родителя.